# Vertx application doesn't stop via command

Tags: java, vert.x

I'm trying to follow instructions on [official vert.x site](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/) related to starting/stopping vertx verticle gracefully by passing jvm arg

> You can also start an application in background using:
>
> `java -jar my-verticle-fat.jar start -Dvertx-id=my-app-name`
>
> If **my-app-name** is not set, a random id will be generated, and printed on the command prompt.
>
> You can pass run options to the start command:
>
> `java -jar my-verticle-fat.jar start -Dvertx-id=my-app-name -cluster`

However, I can't get it to stop using `-Dvertx-id=my-app-name` now that I started the application with below command:

`java -jar my-verticle-fat.jar stop my-app-name`

It only stops with the random ID it generated and not this ID I defined in JVM arg. Anyone know how this is done to stop process gracefully without killing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

`java -jar my-verticle-fat.jar start --vertx-id=my-app-name -cluster`

Then, to stop it:

`java -jar my-verticle-fat.jar stop my-app-name`

Comment: is `...stop my-app-name` command intended to trigger `MyVerticle#stop()` method? If not, how do I trigger it?